# Migrating flex 3 to flex 4.5 mobile development

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex3, flex4.5

I recently started developing mobile applications using Flex 4.5. I try to migrate an web application done flex 3 to flex 4.5 the following error shown.

```
Definition mx.core:Container could not be found.
```

What we can use instead of this in flex 4.5 mobile application. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this http://flashcongress.cn/devnet/flex/articles/migrating-flex-apps-part3.html

please check this

"Flex Build Path" -> "Library Path" -> "Component set:" to "Spark only"

if your settings is as above then change them to

"Flex Build Path" -> "Library Path" -> "Component set:" to "MX + Spark"

this will solve the problem